# Is creating a voltage rail loop good or bad practice?

Tags: pcb-design, layout, ldo, 3.3v, soc

I am still new to PCB design but I often run into this.

Say I have a USB connector on the bottom of a board, a SoC on the top, an LDO somewhere in the middle, and miscellaneous stuff on the sides. It's often not clear the best place to tap into VCC for everything while I'm still moving things around and I end up connecting it in multiple places back to the source, creating a 'ring of power.'

Loosely related, I've found when running long runs of LED strips that effectively form a loop, it works better to connect both ends to +ve and ground. Otherwise the furthest end of the LED strips have more resistance and they get dimmer towards the end. Does the same thinking apply?

My approach thus far has been "it can't hurt," but can it? Should there just always be only one path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having low impedance on the power rail is always a good thing. So multiple power paths aren't bad in general.
However a star-pattern or power plane can be better if emi is a concern.
Any ripple caused by sudden power draw can propagate to other parts better if you only have a single "circle" line.
What you may also watch out for is proper blocking capacitors so you don't get any ripple into your components.

Comment: okay good to know. Every IC has accompanying 0.1uf, and for bigger things also  10uf positioning right next to the IC. I know that much from inspecting other designs and reading data sheets, but I'm still ignorant to nuance with these things.

Answer (score 10):

A related peripheral issue worth being aware of:

If you have analog measurement points on a board, whether internally sourced or from external sources, then at the signal levels usually dealt with by uC ADCs substantial error can occur if earth reference voltages are not meticulously managed.

This often requires

- Microcontroller grounds
- Signal source grounds to be star connected to a common point
- Taking exceptional measures to ensure that unrelated signals do not flow in the ground paths.

---

Example:

On a PCB with onboard aDC (maybe in a microcontroller or separate) Measure the voltage between eg power supply input ground point and various ground points on the board. An oscilloscope allows you to see AC and DC.

As the circuit operates note how the voltages do (or don't) vary.
If you are driving eg a relay you may see some mV  or maybe 10's of mV difference. A 10 bit ADC with a say 2.048V reference has 2 mV per bit resolution. Use it on a circuit board without due care and you will easily reduce it to 9 or 8 bits effective. Maybe even worse. Ask me (and many others) how we know :-).

Comment on these claims welcome.

Comment: thanks for that tip. I am indeed playing with some external ADCs, but they appear to work just fine bread boarded or on a home milled PCB laid out without much thought. I am however using really fat traces so I guess that helps.

Comment: @Kez Such things work well sometimes always and sometimes while Murphy is looking the other way.  Measure the voltage between eg power supply input ground point and various ground points on the board. An oscilloscope allows you to see AC and DC. As circuit operates note how voltages do (or don't) vary. If driving eg a relay you may see mV yo maybe 1's of mV difference. A 10 bit ADC with a say 2.048V reference has 2 mV per bit resolution. Use it on a circuit board without dur care and you will easily reduce it to 9 or 8 bits effective. Maybe even worse. Ask me (and many others) how we know :-).

Comment: I don't really understand why everyone speaks of "star" layouts - in year 2023 nobody is using 2 layer boards any longer. At a bare minimum 4 layers with at least 1 GND layer in the stack-up. Which in turn means you'll have a GND copper pour all over the board. And the way to deal with sensitive parts (like RF or voltage regulator power ground) is to have a separate copper pour area for those things and connect it at a single point to the main GND near the GND connector of the board. I'm not seeing any stars :) What am I missing?

Comment: @Lundin You may be missing nothing :-. My point is that IF you want ADC's to work to eg 10 bits accuracy then exceptional care must be taken to ensure that varying voltages from unrelated sources do not occur in the measuring loop. IF a ground layer can ensure that you have say under 0.5 mV DC variation or noise across all points that should be at common ground in your analog circuit then you may get 10 bits (at 2 mV/bit) with an eg 2.048V reference. If your reference is lower or you want eg 12 bits you need even less variation. Yes?

Comment: So a separate plane/pour then, ground the ADC/MCU analog grounds there, as well as the ground of the Vref to the ADC and the ground of any decoupling caps involved. Probably good enough for most purposes? More so than ground layout, the key is probably to pick a good, dedicated voltage ref of the "LDO:ish" variety since most noise tends to enter through the supply.

Comment: @Lundin  If you have the capacity for a separate Analog ground plane then that would probably work well enough. I've had to deal with this without such a "luxury" available and found that something akin to "star" grounds for analog was in order. Even a branching analog ground distribution may suffice.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon That's the point where the PCB designer really ought to ask for more layers (and their manager/customer ought to listen). 6 layers aren't that much more expensive these days. The PCB I work with right now is an RF one with 6 layers 0.8mm. The extra PCB cost is similar to adding a couple of extra components to the BoM, so it ought to be one of the last things to cheap out on.

Comment: @Lundin   TBD in my case. I'm about to implement a solar powered latrine lighting system for use in regfugee camps. It needs to work enough magic to look after itself in all sun conditions,  plus monitor usage and state of usability, plus provide (probably) mesh radio connectivity to other latrines (who would have thought ? :-) ), plus cellphone network interface for management and more - and cost under about $US14.  Every $ corner that can be cut will be - while still working brilliantly (pun noticed) and super reliably. If N layers cost little more compared to other things they will happen.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Sounds hairy to just get your hands on any half-decent RF part with that budget! Let alone making something that conforms to radio regulations. Best of luck :)

Comment: @Lundin Your wishes for luck are most welcome :-) Really! ||  The RF component is a significant but not major part of the budget. || I am well versed with dealing with Chinese suppliers (about 6 months in China total, many factory visits.) || I asked for 1,000 and 10,000 volume pricing on various widely availablke modules. These are based on components from well established non-Chinese manufacturers and assembled prices are usually well below the component cost from non-Chinese sources . || I got (too) many) responses. A danger I was aware of from past experience. || When it gets to finer ...

Comment: ... design very careful due diligence is required. VERY> Components are usually genuine. Their are out of spec risks/failed test parts/ ... . It's doable and most and maybe all mayve be genuine. I can (probably) get about 1 km range regulatory acceptable mesh modules for around $US1. LORA transcievers for under $US2 and GPRS 2G (cellphone) modules for under $US5. (These can be gateways to a mesh system so cost is spread).  2G is being turned off in NZ next year :-( - likely available in eg Africa for some while yet. 4G modules are dearer but still affordable. ||

Comment: Challenging? Oh yes ! || Doable - I believe so.  Better be :-)

Comment: It is usually more important to make sure that the ground currents have a way to flow where needed than it is to try to block them from where they aren't wanted.

Comment: @JohnDoty The main point of my  answer, expanded on in the comments is that  FOR ANALOG MEASUREMENTS it is as you say important that digital currents flow where they are needed. Where they are NOT needed is transiting the path across which analog measurements are made. Variations in digital related currents do not need to create variations in unrelated measurements. As above, with a 2.048V reference and 12 bit ADC (or DAC)  2 mV variation is one bit. With a 1.024V reference it's 2 bits. With an eg 20 bit Sigma Delta modulator 1 mV noise with a 4.096V reference is 5 bits of signal :-(.

Comment: In mixed signal systems, the boundary between analog and digital is murky. I've seen many more student projects get into trouble from blocking a return current than I have from failing to isolate. But yes, if you're trying to get 10 PPM photometry from a CCD (done that), you need to carefully do both.

Comment: @JohnDoty  I agree with you that proper design is needed in all cases. I have seen on-chip uC 10 bit ADC's with about 2 bits variation due to ground current variations. Meeting all requirements well is tyhe easy spec. Doing it is the harder reality: -). ie I suspect we agree reasonably well in practice.

Answer (score 3):

A closed rail loop is a nightmare for signal processing since any magnetic flux changes through it (and normal household environments have magnetic fields of the 50Hz or 60Hz variety, causing hum in all audio equipment) will induce a circular voltage leading to a circular current offsetting the magnetic flux change.  That makes the circular rail useless as a reference.

Now naturally audio and measurement circuits are worst affected by this: the solution is to keep ground reference tracks parallel to the corresponding signal tracks without introducing loops, and to use solid ground pours for voltage supply and bypass capacitor purposes.

A ring architecture is not really good as a ground pour; a criss-crossed area works reasonably with reduced copper requirements.

So the answer is: for many purposes a ground loop can and does hurt.  An LED strip is not really concerned with signal processing; whether it makes a difference to your holiday season decorations when the central tree is hit by lightning is debatable.

Comment: But unless you can get rid of *all* ground loops (and you often can't), it's better to have more of them. The worst case is a single ground loop. "Let ground abound" is usually good advice.

Comment: "Necessary" ground loops come about because of multiple channels with grounded inputs joining, and amps having grounded outputs.  But most amplifiers these days use opamps, and a summing/inverting opamp with a "grounded" input can get its reference ground from input and and output grounds in the exact same proportion as on the positive input, but with resistances in the order of 10ohms.  That puts enough resistance into the ground loops to let basically all of the ground loop voltages end up at the resistors forming the virtual ground point, and no net hum survives in the differentials.

Comment: Single-ended interfaces between subsystems are very common in general. And remember, crosstalk is reciprocal: it's often not enough to make your low-level external interfaces differential. Can you make all your logic differential? Can you do differential interfaces between every on-board chip?

Comment: @JohnDoty You don't need "differential interfaces", you just need to have the ground reference paths accompanying the signal paths.  That way magnetic fields don't have much area to go between them.  Only when you need to splice a ground reference do ground bus implementations (the mentioned resistor networks) come into play for breaking up a ground loop.  I have an overland line passing in 200m distance and work with amps; I have a bit of experience with managing magnetic field impacts and other noise sources...

Comment: That's a start. But suppose you have two subsystems, on common power, with a signal connection between them. You put in a ground conductor by the signal. Good, but now you have a ground loop that will carry the current due to any external AC flux. That's often not so good. But if you have a *lot* of low impedance ground loops, they share the current, so it's less of a problem. A single ground loop is the worst case.

Comment: @JohnDoty There is no requirement to have earth on two connected devices.  For a general-purpose device like an amp with security concerns, you can do the Earth/ground connection via a high-powered bridge rectifier.  That gives you 1.2V of high impedance headroom for avoiding a ground loop, but enough conductance to blow a fuse rather than anything else in case of an electric mishap.  When everything else fails, there are DIs.  There's lots of tools in the box.

Comment: They need low impedance connections to power. If they share power, that means low impedance to common. With ordinary single ended interfaces, that's also connected to signal common, and that needs to be connected between the devices. And there are often loops of devices as well.

Comment: @JohnDoty Power supply rejection on modern opamps is more than good enough to make sharing the problems of a common power supply ground (which the opamps actually need only for the bypass capacitors from the actual power rails) with the signal reference ground routing nonsensical.

Comment: Opamps? Lots of other components than opamps.

Comment: @JohnDoty Those were the days...  Sometimes things like a low-impedance high-quality first stage may be done with discrete transistors, but when they are, it tends to be for a low-impedance differential input, by virtue of an actual balanced input stage or an input source without actual ground reference, like a properly connected moving coil record player pickup.  But beating something like an OPA1612 for low impedance inputs or OPA1642 for high impedances these days is barely realistic.  And being better in the intermediate range is still a tall order.  Little reason to accept hum...

Comment: There are more applications than audio, too.

Comment: The ancient J309 is *much* quieter above a kHz than your OPA1642. And the OPA1642 isn't fast enough for the radiation detection applications I work on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149382/discussion-between-user107063-and-john-doty).

Answer (score 1):

I would say avoid sharing impedance between loads. Star connection is best for that and make sure you have some capacitance there.

Point is when you have multiple loads sharing a trace from the source you will have common impedance and resistance. Meaning that if load one suddenly increases current consumption load 2 sees a voltage drop. This would be bad in sensitive circuits.

BAD

[image: Loads behind shared trace]

STAR

[image]

Star is a better way to insulate subsystems from each other. Capacitance in the junction helps to cancel the effects of shared impedance to the left of the junction.

If you plan on using a solid supply plane you should have at least 6 layers and use only two for signal routing. See this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySuUZEjARPY&t=4826s&ab_channel=Altium

Answer (score 1):

Every current that flows from your power supply on the power conductor returns to your power supply by some other path. It's *these* loops that are EMI trouble, not loops in the power conductor itself. The more area such a loop surrounds, the more potential trouble.

So, ideally, the power distribution geometry should reflect the current flow in the signal network, keeping the loop area small. Bypass capacitors around current concentrations help by allowing the high frequency components of the current to return through ground as well as power distribution conductors.

A star network for power distribution is usually only a good idea if the signal flow matches it. But sometimes it's a good idea to isolate patches of circuitry, routing *all* power, signal, and ground connections through a narrow "bridge". A disciplined form of star connection.